# How to take advantage of the standard library

Tags: c++, std

I've been coding with c++ for over 2 years already, started by independently learning it with online guides/books. Now, after 2 years, I think I master the language pretty well. One thing though I haven't paid attention to:

It's about the standard c++ library. Recently I had to deal with abstract io streams and buffers, and I realized that I don't know anything about powerful use of them. I only know the basic containers and io operations.

So is there any good sites/books where I can learn how to take great advantage of the streams/library in general, and learn the architecture of the library? Links to sites would be appreciated :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216374/where-to-learn-more-about-streams-in-c. Look at the selected answer: The best book on the subject is C++ IOStreams & Locales by langer & Kreft. This covers stuff on deriving your own streambufs etc. that most books don't touch. I could live without the locales stuff, however.

Comment: So, you mastered c++ in only 2 years? You can consider yourself a wunderkind :) If you missed the standard library, then you have a big hole in your c++ expertise.

Comment: How did you live without the STL container classes like map, set or vector? Reinventing the wheel?

Comment: http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1044/Notes/C04.IO.pdf, probably too basic for you , but good

Comment: I do have used many standard library features, including map, also unique_ptr and others. Just want to more thoroughly use its features!

Answer (score 2):

I think these books are a good source:

- The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference,
  Nicolai M. Josuttis,
  ISBN 0201379260
- Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve the Use of the Standard Template Library,
  Scott Meyers,
  ISBN 0201749629